# Gitlab CI variable before script with curl raises YAML syntax error

Tags: json, bash, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

I am defining a variable `JWT`, I will store in it a token which I will use later inside the code.
I'm going to obtain it at the `before_script` step through a curl call.

The problem is that when I try to run the pipeline, it fails with the error:

> Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml: Included file `.gitlab-ci.yml`
> does not have valid YAML syntax!

I have already read this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584694/8097791) in order to properly interpolate `USER` and `PASS` environment variables.

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
build-dist:
  environment:
    name: develop
  variables:
    JWT: ""
  stage: build
  image: node:16-alpine
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - yarn.lock
    paths:
      - node_modules
      - .yarn
  before_script:
    - if [ -z "$USER" ] || [ -z "$PASS" ]; then exit 1; fi
    - apk add curl 
    - JWT=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "'"$USER"'","password": "'"$PASS"'"}' "https://example.com/token")

  script: 
    - yarn install --pure-lockfile --cache-folder .yarn
    - yarn build
```

How should I correct the follow line inside my `.gitlab-ci.yml` in order to make it work?

```
- JWT=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "'"$USER"'","password": "'"$PASS"'"}' "https://example.com/token")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a handy tip for such GitLab CI issues:

- assuming your have a GitLab repo on `https://gitlab.com/user/project`,
- you can browse the page `https://gitlab.com/user/project/-/ci/lint`
- then paste the contents of the offending `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, and click on "Validate" to get more feedback (typically, the error line number, etc.)

Regarding the YAML snippet at stake, the crux of the issue is the `- JWT=$(…)` line as you mentioned in the question, more precisely:

- from a YAML point of view, the string `JWT=…` is not explicitly quoted,
- and as this text contains a `:`,
- the YAML parser then sees it as a map, i.e., as if you had written:

  ```
  - username: "NAME"
    other_key: "val"
  ```

To solve this, it appears you'd just need to "quote" this sequence item with `'` or `"` and thus write a line of the form `- "JWT=…"`, then escape the quotes accordingly inside… but I'd rather suggest (to avoid ugly escapes!) to rely on the so-called [block style of YAML](https://yaml-multiline.info/) → this leads to:

```sh
- |
  JWT=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "'"$USER"'","password": "'"$PASS"'"}' "https://example.com/token")
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem I was facing, actually I ended up with the same solution reading the at the gitlab documentation at the section [split-long-commands](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#split-long-commands) but this will be useful for someones